# Can anybody help be with immediate less than and immediate greater than from a number query in solr

Tags: database, solr

```
var strQuery = client_education.query().q(
    'all_type:current_affairs AND active:1 AND ca_id:123)
var next = client_education.query().q(
    'all_type:current_affairs AND active:1 AND ca_id>123) 
    // should return the greater than 123 ca_id from database

// var previous = client_education.query().q(
    'all_type:current_affairs AND active:1 AND ca_id<123) 
    // should return the less than 123 ca_id from database
```

How can I retrieve values greater than and less than the given id (123) in solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Range searches can be done using](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#range-searches) `[start TO end]`, where `[]` is used to mean including, while `{}` is used to mean excluding the start/end.

For any value larger than `123`:

```
ca_id:{123 TO *]
```

For any value smaller than `123` (not including):

```
ca_id:[* TO 123}
```

This assume that your fields are configured as proper integer fields. If you have configured them a text or string fields, this won't work (and you need to reconfigure them), since `111111` sorts before `123` and thus is considered less than `123`.

But as long as you've configured your fields as numeric / integer fields, the range syntax works as expected.